# How to wrap a block of template code in different elements depending on a condition?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, routerlink

My component has 2 props: `link` and `isExternal`. Depending on the latter, I'll wrap my template code either in a `<NuxtLink` (equivalent of native `Vue` `<router-link>`) or in a `<a>` element.

The code below achieves that by using twice the same template code - which is obviously atrocious.

Yet I can't think of a simple way to do it elegantly. Any idea?

```
<template>
  <NuxtLink
    v-if="!isExternal"
    to="link"
  >
    <div
      class="btn"
      :style="{
        'background-color': backgroundColor,
        'color': textColor
      }"
    >
      <img
        v-if="image"
        :src="image"
        class="image"
      >

      <div>{{ text }}</div>

      <svg-icon name="arrow-right" class="arrow" />
    </div>
  </NuxtLink>

  <a
    v-else
    href="link"
    target="_blank"
  >
    <div
      class="btn"
      :style="{
        'background-color': backgroundColor,
        'color': textColor
      }"
    >
      <img
        v-if="image"
        :src="image"
        class="image"
      >

      <div>{{ text }}</div>

      <svg-icon name="arrow-right" class="arrow" />
    </div>
  </a>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `component` element like this:

```js
<template>
  <component
    :is="computedTag"
    v-bind="computedProps"
  >
    <div
      class="btn"
      :style="{
        'background-color': backgroundColor,
        'color': textColor
      }"
    >
      <img
        v-if="image"
        :src="image"
        class="image"
      >

      <div>{{ text }}</div>

      <svg-icon name="arrow-right" class="arrow" />
    </div>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['link', 'isExternal'],
  computed: {
    computedTag() {
      return this.isExternal ? 'a' : 'nuxt-link';
    },
    computedProps() {
      return this.isExternal
        ? { href: this.link, target: '_blank' }
        : { to: this.link };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```